# Find file with today date using Powershell

Tags: powershell

When I create file with today date is ok but when I want to try send file to ftp server I get error "File not found"

It is my code :

```
$TodayDate = $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
open myserver
user myuser mypass
put C:\MyPath\44_$TodayDate.csv
quit
exit
```

How to send file with today date ?

Comment: Hmmm ... don't you have to create the file first?

Comment: I have file, I have a few scripts who create files and I want send this file into FPT using 1 script with few put methods

Comment: Which FTP client are you using?

Comment: I use only this script. When i try send file with "normal" name it is not a problem. Problem is when i try "read" data

Comment: Try double-quoting the path and filename as in `put "C:\MyPath\44_$TodayDate.csv"`. By double-quoting the string, the variable inside it gets parsed, so the resulting string becomes `C:\MyPath\44_2019-03-21.csv`

Comment: I don't understand. Please write me exacly what i need to write.

Comment: I did tell you exactly what to write.. Change the line `put C:\MyPath\44_$TodayDate.csv` into `put "C:\MyPath\44_$TodayDate.csv"`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code looks like a mixture of powershell code and a (static) FTP.exe script file.

FTP.exe does neither understand embedded powershell nor environment variables.

You **can** generate the ftp-script file per PowerShell from a template (here string) like this:

```
$TodayDate = $(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)
@"
open myserver
user myuser mypass
put C:\MyPath\44_$TodayDate.csv
quit
exit
"@ | Set-Content ftp.scr -Enc ASCII

&ftp.exe -s:ftp.scr
```